# Priority power switch - capacitor placement and DC-DC at the output

Tags: switching

I am building a PCB using the [TPS212x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2121.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1701015663120&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fgr.mouser.com%252F) IC to switch between the highest Vin available at any time (3.8Vbat or 12V solar panels). At the output of the TPS212x, I am placing a [MP28167](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/277/MP28167GQ-2899693.pdf) DC-DC automatic Boost/buck IC that configures the voltage to give me always 5V. So basically I always want 5V for my electronics regarding of the two Vin(s). My hookup:

[image: Power switch kicad]

Two questions:

1. instead of placing the capacitors C13 to C16 and C17,C18,C19 right at the input of the Vin of the DC-DC (as I would like to), I placed them before the Power Switching/priority IC as I am afraid that if the capacitors are at the input of the Power/priority switching IC will cause issue. Imagine this scenario:
   -The 12V are active on the Power switch IC so the capacitors will be changed with 12V, and then say the power switches to the Vbat,
   -the capacitors will still be charged at 12V and these 12V will discharge themselves on the battery!
   I cannot tell if the [TPS212x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2121.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1701015663120&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fgr.mouser.com%252F) Power switch IC has such reverse protection, I think it doesn't as I couldn't find such info in the datasheet and judging from its internal diagram, the mosfet just shorts the Output with the input voltage so no such reverse protection:

[image: TPS212x priority power]

2. The input of the DC-DC IC will be changing from 3.8V to ~12V fast. Won't this cause switching miscalculations inside the DC-DC IC and cause its output to (for example) let the 12V pass through it for some useconds? Maybe miliseconds. I will check that when I build the PCB, but I would like to know if there is some kind of technique to suppress such faulty case to the output, or if there is something in the datasheets that helps me theoretically check if this could happen.

Comment: _”as I am afraid that if the capacitors are at the input of the Power/priority switching IC will cause issue”_ Please simulate and test. A hunch can be a dangerous design criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the PCB. In the datasaheet of the IC it mentions it has reverse current blocking feature:

[image: Reverse current blocking]

So it protects the lower voltage source from sinking current from the higher voltage source. Therefore I can use capacitors at the output of the [TPS212x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2121.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1701015663120&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fgr.mouser.com%252F).

The DC-DC also Needs to have capacitors close to its input, otherwise its input voltage would jump to ~30V due to the switching on the inductor. So I added capacitors there as well.

[[image: DC-DC with TPS2121]